# Is there any fast way to rescale page through CSS?

Tags: css, resize, window-resize

[image: 25% scale]

[image: 100% scale]

Have a following problem. When I created page, I didn't notice that customized all content to the scale of 25%. So when I return page to normal scale it looks like a mess. So I'm wondering, is there any way to make everything look the same as on 25% scale or should I manually change everything in CSS?

Comment: Please share some of your CSS, specifically your method of applying `font-size` to elements. That should help in finding a solution :)

Comment: Each modification you will have to do later you will have to remember to scale everything down to 25% first. So yeah, silly mistake but take your loss and correct the error. I'm sure you won't mess up next time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When tackling an issue, it's important to identify the source. In your case, it was user error - and the fix would be going back and adjusting your stylesheet for native scaling.

Resorting to a scale factor would just be duct taping it, but for the sake of completeness, the `zoom` CSS property does what you wish, with a huge asterisk: It's non-standard, it's **not** supported in Firefox, and you shouldn't use it.